# Can WebStorm automatically format the code when I am writing?

Tags: webstorm

In Visual Studio when I type some special characters like ;} it will automatically format related code segment, but in WS, nothing happens. I tried to find that option but ended without fruits.

```
// e.g. In VS, if we type something like:
var abc=123
// and then type ; it will be formatted as:
var abc = 123;
```

I am trying to understand why many people love WebStorm as a JS IDE. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option is provided in WebStorm 8 (coming soon) - see [IDEA-120066](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120066)

Answer (score 1):

PC: Ctrl + Alt + L 
MAC: Command + Alt + L 
Here you can find a nice tutorial by John Lindquist: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIxDar8CbJA

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used VS recently so I'm not sure what `;}` does, but WebStorm can definitely expand templates. Above a function declaration, try typing `/**` and then Enter, for example - WebStorm will automatically generate a JSDoc heading.

Look also in the IDE Settings under Live Templates -> JavaScript. Typing `us<Enter>` will insert a `"use strict;"` etc.

If you want to reformat code, there's an option under `Code -> Reformat Code` to reformat the selected text (or the entire file). Though probably it's best to get used to writing code abiding by [JavaScript style guidelines](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Style-Guide) :) Comes in handy when you don't have an IDE at hand, e.g. editing on GitHub, in a terminal, **on StackOverlfow** (cough) etc.

Also, you should enable JSHint, which would highlight `abc=123` as needing style improvements.

Comment: Ahh, sorry I didn't make it clear. When I wrote ;} I was not saying shortcuts or snippets. Just typing the ; or } in the code I am writing. e.g. After typing "abc=123" if I type ";", it will be formatted as "abc = 123;".

Comment: I believe that there are options to auto-format when you save, but would have to look up the details.

Comment: Autoformat when you save or type `;` just teaches bad habits. I would not recommend enabling it even if it exists.

Comment: I noticed the reformat option and I found the code style configurations are really detailed. But I don't think auto formatting teaches bad habits as I also use sublime text to do some quick edits or single-file script, and I follow my style strictly. O.O

Comment: StackOverflow, GitHub etc. don't support WebStorm or Sublime autoformatting, that's why I'm saying that sort of autoformatting of code without spaces is a (bad) hack.

Answer (score -1):

select `Code > Reformat Code` from the **main menu**, code formatting popup will appear.