# WebStorm format code on type

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting, refactoring, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have found this question with no apparent working answer to it here.

[Can WebStorm automatically format the code when I am writing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139104/can-webstorm-automatically-format-the-code-when-i-am-writing)

I basically have the exact same question. Really handy feature even in VSCode, saves a lot of time pressing the format shortcut.

Does anyone have an idea how to enable it if even possible?

Answer (score 2):

When **Reformat block on typing '}'** is enabled in `Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys`, enclosed code block is reformatted automatically on entering '**}**';

Reformatting on adding semicolon is not yet implemented, please vote for [IDEA-122070](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122070)

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I found out. I have 'reformat on }' enabled but doesn't quite do the job. :)

Answer (score 1):

WebStorm can't automatically format the code when you are  writing . visit the page to get detail about code format in Webstrome  [Visit page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/reformatting-source-code.html)